# i am passing an array "slot" from blade template and want to get its value in js file like name=slot['name'];

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

i have this blade code and want to get the value of name in $slot's array in the function validateSlot of calender.js . How to get that ?

**My Js Function code :**

```js
$scope.validateSlots = function(x) {
  namee = x['name'];


  return true;
};
```

```html
**And this is my Blade file's code :** 

<div class="table-row table-body" ng-if="validateSlots.apply(this, slot)">
  <div class="user-column table-cell">
    <a class="center-vertically" href="{{route(" worker-profile ", [$slot['id']])}}">
      <div title="{{isset($slot['service_string'])?$slot['service_string']:''}}">

        {{$slot['name']}}
        <span class="total-hours ">
                                                            <span>

                                                            </span>
        </span>

      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$scope.validateSlots = function(x) {
  name = "{{$slot['name']}}"; //array from your controller etc to blade JS file
  return true;
};
```